# PlayHaven SDK with cocos2D-x Wrapper

Tags: wrapper, cocos2d-x, ads, playhaven

I am newbie for cocos2D-x and i am trying to integrate the playhaven sdk under it. I've googled much but unable to have the playhaven sdk for advertisements. I would need the wrapper class for the playhaven sdk Can you suggest me for that.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Search PlayHavenXBridge, you will require to study and use this